# Bouncy Castle and Camellia in NetBeans

Tags: java

I am trying to use Camellia block cipher to encrypt a text.
There is a built in class in Bouncy Castle for camellia.
How can I implement **Camellia** using **Bouncy Castle** in **Net Beans**?

Comment: Import `Bouncy Castle` and then use the methods. What is the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that I am new in encryption programming and I did not find any tutorial about how to use a Block cipher within Bouncy Castle in Net Beans or eclipse. Is there any tutorial/instructions I have missed.